# AngularJS paging directive not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to write a simple paging directive of my own in angularjs.

please see the code at 
http://plnkr.co/edit/M7kIjoKNmIWXOyRDfzZg

When I click "next" I get an exception saying : 
`Non-assignable model expression: 1`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The isolation scope in your directive should be:

```
scope: {
    'currentPage': '@',
    'pageSize': '@',
}
```

Using `=` expects the value to be a reference to a value in the parent scope in order to do two way data binding.  If you want to use `=`, you should make `currentPage` and `pageSize` items on your controller and then do `<paging page-size="pageSize" current-page="currentPage"></paging>`.

**Edit**: Using `@` will make `currentPage` and `pageSize` strings, so you will need to use `parseInt`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're assigning the model of currentPage in your scope:

```
'currentPage':'=',
```

But when you create the directive in index.html you pass in a value

```
<paging page-size="1" current-page="1"></paging>
```

So there are two ways to fix this, one would be to create another variable in your controller called current page and then change your directive to this:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.currentPage = 1;
});
```

html

```
<paging page-size="1" current-page="currentPage"></paging>
```

Or change how you create your scope in your directive to this:

```
 scope:{
   'currentPage':'@',
   'pageSize':'=',
 }
```

you will have to parse it into an int if you use this route, as it comes in as a string